# Databricks job timeout sending message to service bus with spark 3.2.1 and azure-messaging-servicebus sdk

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-servicebus-topics

we have developed a scala job using azure-messaging-servicebus sdk for java (ver 7.8.0) to send messages on service bus topic. All **work fine** as expected using an azure cloud **databricks 9.1 LTS** (with Spark 3.1.2 and scala 2.12), but running the same job **on 10.4 LTS cluster (with Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12) the job fail with the following timeout error**:

```
IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 245600000000 NANOSECONDS
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:123)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
```

Any suggestion about this issue? Databricks 10.4LTS is necessary for PROD environment. Thanks in advance

Comment: **I have noted that the log report a previous error (non fatal) caused by the same library (reactor)**

> 22/05/13 13:04:23 ERROR Schedulers: Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.util.retry.Retry.generateCompanion(Lreactor/core/publisher/Flux;)Lorg/reactivestreams/Publisher;
>  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:68)
>  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(FluxRetryWhen.java:83)
>  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4385)
>  ...

Answer (score 0):

I solve the posted problem implementing **shaded jar** as suggested in [microsoft official document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#dependency-conflict)